# Excel array formula works fine for lesser than "<" operator but not greater than ">" operator

Tags: arrays, excel, operator-keyword

[image: Greater than (does not work)]

[image: Lesser than (works)]

Screenshot of formula attached above.

Any idea why the "lesser than" formula works but the same formula does not work when the operator changes to "greater than"? Any help is much appreciated. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `"1/1/2019"`, use `DATE(2019,1,1)`:

```
=SMALL(IF(A2:A9="A",IF(B2:B9>DATE(2019,1,1),C2:C9)),2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I'm still curious about why it worked fine in one formula but not the other? Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Actually it's not working fine in the other formula. The comparison `B2:B9<"1/1/2019"` is returning TRUE for every row.

Comment: To add to this: in Excel's sort order, any number is smaller than text. The date as text is still text and will always be smaller than any comparison date, even if that date is greater than the date that the text describes.